# QColumnView is rolled to empty column

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt4

I use a QStandardItemModel coupled with QColumnView to display a list of simple hierarchal tree structure. My view has 2 columns, rows on the second columns are children of a item on first column. When user select a item/row on column 1, children of that item/row will be displayed on second column. Now here comes the annoying behavior of the QColumnView: although my list has only 2 columns, whenever user click on an item of the second column, it automatically rolls further to the third column on the right (which is empty).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
categories = {"Develop": ["py", "rb", "h", "html", "css"],
                   "Image": ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "gif", "png"],
                   "Movies": ["avi", "mkv", "mov", "mp4"],
                   "Documents": ["doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "ppt", "pptx"],
                   "Music": ["mp3", "wav"]}
model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
for cat, types in categories.items():
    catItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(cat)
    catItem.setCheckable(True)
    for type in types:
        typeItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(type)
        typeItem.setCheckable(True)
        #typeItem.setSelectable(False)
        catItem.appendRow(typeItem)
    model.appendRow(catItem)
columnView = QtGui.QColumnView()
columnView.setModel(model)

columnView.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The last column is the preview widget, and there is no way to disable it. You cannot even override `createColumn` to get different behaviour.

Comment: How I can same functional ( may be using others views ), but without empty column?